# Trigger Conditional field update in lead based on parent account

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to write a trigger to update field(live to site) in Lead based on some condition.

We have a custom field in Account Account_id__c(ex:25679) which is a number and also similar field(seller_id__c-which is also a number ex:25679) in lead which is also a number. When there is a new account with some account id matches with lead seller id then a field live to site(picklist with values Yes, No) in lead should update with Yes.

## Trigger

```
trigger LTS_Update1 on Account (after update) {
    set<Id> acctIds = new set<Id>();
    map<Id, Account> mapAccount = new map<Id, Account>();
      List<Lead> listLead = new List<Lead>();
    
    for(Account acct : trigger.new) {
        acctIds.add(acct.Id);
        mapAccount.put(acct.Id, acct);
    }
    
    listLead = [SELECT Id, Live_to_site__c, Account__c FROM Lead WHERE Account__c IN : acctIds];    
    
    List<Account> acc=new List<Account>();
    for(Account acct: acc)
    {
    if(acc[0].Account_ID__c == listLead[0].seller_id__c) {
        for(Lead ld : listLead) {
            ld.Live_to_site__c = 'Yes';
          }  
        }
        update listLead;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in your last for loop:

```
    List<Account> acc=new List<Account>();
    for(Account acct: acc)
    {
    if(acc[0].Account_ID__c == listLead[0].seller_id__c) {
        for(Lead ld : listLead) {
            ld.Live_to_site__c = 'Yes';
          }  
        }
        update listLead;
    }
```

You are browsing an empty list.
But for your problem, here's what I suggest:

```
trigger LTS_Update1 on Account (after update, after insert) {
    List<String> acctSellerIds = new List<String>();
    for(Account acct : trigger.new) {
        acctSellerIds.add(acct.Account_id__c);
    }

    String value = 'Yes';
    List<Lead> listLead = [SELECT Id, Live_to_site__c FROM Lead WHERE seller_id__c IN :acctSellerIds AND Live_to_site__c != :value];
    for(Lead lead : listLead){
        lead.Live_to_site__c = value;
    }
    update listLead;
}
```

With that solution, you only request the leads with a Seller Id existing in an Account and with the value Live_to_site__c that must be changed.

Comment: You should also create a trigger for the deletion of an account. To set the value to 'No' on the matching lead.

Comment: Looks like something is not fine but I am getting the following error after saving the record and also live to site field is not updating  " System.StringException: Invalid id: 2543: External entry point" a

Comment: What's the type of your custom field "Account_Id__c"?

Comment: It's Text data type

Comment: Ok I updated my answer. Also you should consider to change the "Account_Id__c" field type if it's supposed to be a number.

Comment: Now I am not getting any error but it's not updating live to site field

Comment: Are you sure that the field Live_to_site__c is set to 'No' by default? I updated my answer.

Comment: Hey Martin Thanking you very much able to sort it out.

Comment: I'm glad it's working. Just be careful because you have to write a case for an account deletion. To remove the 'Yes' property of the lead. You're welcome.